# JTable JComboBox is defaulting to display 1st item when list is expanded

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, jlist

I have been trying to determine why my JComboBox is displaying the 1st item in the list through numerous Google searches, but I'm struggling to find relevant help. It could be that I don't know the correct terminology (hence the overly specific title of this question) and thus not finding the information that would explain my issue. I checked out the JComboBox API, and few of the listeners and models that it uses, but they did not seem likely candidates.

The JComboBox in question is inside a JTable, so I am not aware if that changes the default behaviour of it. The code I am using is as below:

```
//row and col are final due to usage inside anonymous inner class
public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(final int row, final int col)
{
    String[] listItems = new String[arrayList.getSize()];
    int i = -1;

    for(String s : arrayList)
    {
        i++;
        listItems[i] = s;
    }

    JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<>(listItems);
    box.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
    {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            {
                if(e.getItem().equals("Add/Edit Projectile"))
                {
                    //Where Editor is a JFrame that will be opened 
                    new Editor();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    DefaultCellEditor list = new DefaultCellEditor(box);
}
```

Please note that the Arraylist in my program does not contain Strings, but instead a more complicated set of custom objects that I believe would distract from the main issue.

I haven't included a Renderer for JComboBox's in the JTable as I was happy enough with the way it appeared, and figured that my problem was more going to be something I have neglected to implement in the model/implemented wrong.

I've also provided a couple of screenshots to better portray my problem. The first image is when the JComboBox is not selected, and simply displaying the currently selected item.
[image: Unselected, in default state]

The second image is when I have just clicked the JComboBox to bring up the list. As depicted, it will immediately bring up that first item, no matter what it is.
[image: Selected, with list expanded]

If anyone has any suggestions as to where to look/solutions, I would be very grateful.

---

EDIT

My particular table has two columns, where the left column is a variable name, and the right column is the value associated with the variable. The tables role is to display the properties of a selected object, where each value for different variable for different objects are likely to not be the same.

In this particular case, the cell displays a JComboBox with all the available Projectiles in the game we are making. Each enemy has a different type of projectile it defaults to. So when I click on a different enemy in our game area, the table will display all of their current properties (defaults if they have not been changed).

Enemies do have a getter for the Projectile, so I could determine what the currently selected enemy is, get it's projectile, do a toString() to find how it is to be represented in the list, and do a setValueAt().

The only problem is at the moment it is always selecting the first item in the list when the list is expanded.

Comment: To start with, don't use the `ItemListener in the `CellEditor`, add a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel` and monitor the changes to the cell value.  Second, what else should the `JComboBox` display?  You've not set the selected value to anything...

Comment: I will change over to the TableModelListener. IS there particular benefits of doing it that way, regardless of whether they relate to my issue or not? Always happy to learn better programming practice!

The table really should only display the toString() of my Custom Object that is represented in each item in the list. The only event that will need to be tracked is when the "Add/Edit Projectile" item is clicked, as that will need to bring up a new JDialog. Other than that, they are simply representations of the backend data.

Comment: The main reason is, it's not the responsibility of the editor or the model to make decisions about what should happen when a user makes a selection.  The editor is responsible for allowing the user to pick or change the value of the cell, the model is responsible for managing the data

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I'll remember that for my future implementations. I'll also make sure to change the implementation of my current table, so that it adheres to this paradigm. 

Thanks you very much for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the values for the `JComboBox` are dynamically generated for each row, you should be able to just prepare the `CellEditor` ahead of time, for example...

```
JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4"});
DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(cb);

JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(5, 1));
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(editor);
```

This will set the selected value of the editor to the value of the cell when the editing process starts

[image][image]

**Updated**

In the case where the combobox values are dynamically generate per row, you could do something more like...

```
JComboBox cb = new JComboBox();
DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(cb) {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        JComboBox editor = (JComboBox) getComponent();
        String[] listItems = new String[arrayList.getSize()];
        int i = -1;
        for (String s : arrayList) {
            i++;
            listItems[i] = s;
        }

        DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(listItems);
        editor.setModel(model);
        editor.setSelectedItem(value);
        return editor;
    }
};

JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(5, 1));
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(editor);
```

Note the use of `editor.setSelectedItem(value);`, this will set the selected value to the cells current value...

You could also re-use the model, clearing it each time and re-filling it with new values.  You might find this more efficient if you have a large number of rows as you won't need to constantly create a new model each time a cell is edited

Comment: I will edit my question, as this actually won't apply to my situation. In short, essentially all rows are different, and there are only two columns. Each row may have a different cell editor and renderer. I'll update the question now, and see if it changes how I would implement a fix.

Comment: @Stevo Updated with dynamical row values

Comment: I'm still having issues with the 1st value being displayed as the selected item when the list is expanded. I don't know if this changes the question, but the value is only displayed as that for the duration of the list being expanded. After you click away from the JComboBox to make it so that it does not select a value, it will go back to showing the proper value. Does that make sense, or have I just confused things? I can add another picture to the original post if clarification is needed.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Ok, I've read through the link you provided in the last comment, so I will get to work on providing a quick example. I will add it to my original post when I have it completed. Cheers

Comment: After trying to create a stand alone application as suggested, I have not been able to get the same issue to occur. The JComboBox in the table worked as you suggested. It seems like the main program I am working on has some issue in it that is causing this to occur, but to include all of the potentially relevant code would not be appropriate (The table code I have is close to 1000 lines long). If I do find my issue, I will make sure to post the solution here, but sadly I believe this is very specific to my application. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction MadProgrammer.

Comment: The problem ended up being a way that I was searching for the currently selected value, it was essentially refreshing the box every time, so there was no previously selected item. The issue is resolved now.

Thank you so much for your help today, while it might not have solved my problem, I learn a lot about a few different pieces, so that is definitely good. I've also accepted this response as the answer as I believe the information provided will be useful for anyone else who reads this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Thow this is an oldie...

Your problem is most likely you don't implement "equals" in the class used in the combo.

The Combo needs to select the current item when it is being prepared and does so by iterating through the elements of the model and selects the first one that is equal to the value in the cell. If none is encountered then it leaves the combo as is (either first element or the last used element in a previous cell edit)

Comment: Great. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should default to the previously selected element:

```
//...
Object selectedItem = box.getSelectedItem();
//Add some elements to the jComboBox
box.setSelectedItem(selectedItem);
```

Comment: Since the OP has only done `JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<>(listItems);` without adding any more values, it's not going to do much other than leave the currently selecte item selected, which is probably the first item anyway...

Comment: Should this particular bit of code be added to a PopMenuListener()? So if I were to click on the JComboBox, I assume that the listener will receive the notification, and then I'd set the currently selected value there?

Comment: And in relation to MadProgrammer's comments on my question, how would I apply this particular idea to the TableModelListener? Or are these ideas incompatible?

Comment: @Stevo They are different parts of the program